# Named non-contiguous range cannot referred to via Name.RefersToRange - why & how to overcome (elegantly)?

Tags: excel, vba

I got stumped by a rather weired behaviour of Excel (tested on Office Pro 2016 and Office 365).
It appears as if `Name.RefersToRange` breaks when referring to a non-contiguous range.

See this test procedure

```
Public Sub test()
  Dim n As Name
  With ActiveWorkbook
    For Each n In .Names                                  ' remove all preexisting names
      n.Delete
    Next n
    
    Call .Names.Add("rPass", "=Sheet1!$A$1:$C$3")         ' create a new contiguous named range
    Call .Names.Add("rFail", "=Sheet1!$A$1,Sheet1!$C$3")  ' create a new non-contigous named range

    Debug.Print .Names("rPass").RefersTo                  ' runs fine Output: =Sheet1!$A$1:$C$3
    Debug.Print .Names("rPass").RefersToRange.Address     ' runs fine Output: $A$1:$C$3
    
    Debug.Print .Names("rFail").RefersTo                  ' runs fine Output: =Sheet1!$A$1,Sheet1!$C$3
    Debug.Print .Names("rFail").RefersToRange.Address     ' crashes with Error 1004
  End With
End Sub
```

I found a clumsy workaround like this

```
Public Function FunkyRefersToRange(rng As Name) As Range
  Dim r As Range
  Set r = Range(Mid(rng, 2))    ' create a local range by stripping the leading equal sign of the reference
  Set FunkyRefersToRange = r
End Function
```

With that you can now write (as long the correct worksheet is selected)

```
Debug.Print FunkyRefersToRange(.Names("rFail")).Address
```

But I'd like to understand **why** non-contiguous ranges cannot be referenced via `Name.RefersToRange` and how to overcome that limitation more elegantely than shown above.

Comment: Works fine here. What are your regional settings - do you normally use commas or semicolons to separate ranges/function arguments?

Comment: @Rory, thanks for the quick reply! I'm running this on a German installation. So the separators in Excel itself are semicolons, but in VBA they are always recorded as commas. I wouldn't know how to convince VBA to also use semicolons - although I'd prefer to stick with commas.

Comment: Is it a German language version of Excel, or just German regional settings?

Comment: @Rory, it's a German version of Excel. However, on my privat machine I am able to change the localization to English and the decimal separator to dot . (instead of comma) and list separator to comma (instead of semicolon) and the issue went away. Unfortunately this is not an option on my work computers on which I'd need the code to run. - It strikes me as quite odd that MS would not be able to provide a solution that works regardless of localization 

Comment: To be honest, if the formula were in error, you should get an error at the line that creates the name. (I assume the sheet name is correct, since a German Excel would presumably default to Blatt1 not Sheet1). Does `Union(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")).Name = "rFail"` work?

Comment: @Rory, my code above should only illustrate the issue at hand. In real life the ranges would not be defined in code but in Excel via the Names Manager or by clicking together a selection of cells and naming it in the top left names/address field. So I as the one using the named range in my code have no say in how Excel creates the name. When I use macro recorder while creating the named range in Excel, it always records commas although Excel shows semicolons while clicking together the desired cells.

Comment: The problem is using the macro recorder - the recorder is making a ton of assumptions and is very US-centric. Do not use the macro recorder.

Comment: Are you saying that if you create the name manually, `referstorange` doesn't work?

Comment: Exactly that! Only contiguous ranges work.
I guess you can try it for yourself when you go to Control Panel - Region - Additional settings and there change Decimal symbol to comma and List separator to semicolon. After that restart Excel and try what normally should work.

Comment: That definitely looks like a bug in Excel's object model. You mention a repro on Office 365 - try sending detailed repro information through the "send a frown" functionality (the Excel team is actively monitoring this feedback channel). Don't hold your breath for a speedy fix, but making sure Microsoft is aware of the problem would be the first step towards a resolution. In the meantime non-contiguous named ranges should probably be avoided.

Comment: I'll do! Thanks for the support 

Comment: Just ran into this as well...  On my EN-US Excel 2019 machine using `RefersToRange` works on such a name, but on my client's NL-NL Excel 365 machine it crashes with a 1004 error.

Comment: I tried to find other reports of this bug, but couldn't find much of anything.  Did you manage to get this bug reported in a public place, like uservoice or MSDN or such?  If so, could you post the link so I can upvote it too?  My god, who knows how many scripts I've made for my clients over the past years which will break due to this...

Comment: @Carl Colijn, I have reported this via the Excel Feedback Frown feature, but as it seems there is no link I could provide for that to upvote it.
I just submitted the same feedback again and the only thing you get is a: "We appreciate your feedback! Your comments will help us improve." - pretty lame IMHO. 
Via FeedbackHub you at least could look at your previous feedback (although several of mine seem to have disappeared too).

Comment: Just added a report on FeedbackHub too https://aka.ms/AAa295j

Comment: @Scruff.R: thanks for the link, but my Feedback Hub says my account doesn't have access to that feedback.  Ah well; I'll report it separately too then.  Might even work out for the better; who knows!

Comment: Added mine as well; see https://aka.ms/AAa21s2 (don't know if others can access it though)

Comment: I cannot see your feedback either :-(
Does this link work any better? 

feedback-hub:?contextid=464&feedbackid=06def7ef-231d-4650-bc5c-e05e7bf87c92&form=1&src=1

Comment: After months of silence I have now also posted this here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_o365b/potential-bug-with-non-contiguous-named-ranges-in/d48fd74a-abd1-4100-86c9-50e130168737

Answer (score 1):

It should work like this:

```
Sub WhatsInaName()
    Dim disJoint As Range, N As Name, addy As String
    
    Set disJoint = Range("A1,B9")
    disJoint.Name = "jim"
    Set N = disJoint.Name
    addy = N.RefersToRange.Address
    
    MsgBox disJoint.Address & vbCrLf & addy
End Sub
```

[image]

Can you replicate my result on your computer?

Comment: Same problem: I get a runtime error 1004 - application or object defined failure. @Rory's comment to my original post may be on to something, but I have no clue how to overcome the localization (semicolon vs. comma) issue.

Comment: I changed the list separator to comma (from semicolon) and now your code works - it's obviously a MS bug related to that - thank's for the help 

Comment: No response from MS so far, so I raised the issue again here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_o365b/potential-bug-with-non-contiguous-named-ranges-in/d48fd74a-abd1-4100-86c9-50e130168737